# how to unzip file in iphone by programming?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented one iphone application in which i have download one zip file from the server and downloaded in iphone.Now i want to extract zip file by programming.I dont know how it possible and where the extract data will store.
Please help me for this query.

Comment: hey i have solved this issue.if any one need then let me know

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) site contains the objetive c class that we can use to unzip files